# Execute a condition after leaving a certain number of values in a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame as shown below which has around 130k data values.

```
Eng_RPM Veh_Spd
340       56
450       65       
670       0
800       0
890       0
870       0
...       ..
800       0
790       0
940       0
...       ...
1490      67 
1540      78
1880      81
```

I need to have another variable called `Idling Count` which increments the value when ever it finds value in `Eng_RMP` > = 400 and `Veh_Spd` ==0 , the condition is the counter has to start after 960 Data points from the data point which has satisfied the condition, also the above mentioned condition should not be applicable for the first 960 data points as shown below

**Expected Output**

```
Eng_RPM Veh_Spd  Idling_Count
340       56       0
450       65       0
670       0        0
...       ...      0 (Upto first 960 values)  
600       0        0(The Idling time starts but counter should wait for another 960 values to increment the counter value)
...       ...      0
800       0        1(This is the 961st Values after start of Idling time i.e Eng_RPM>400 and Veh_Spd==0)
890       0        2
870       0        3  
...       ..       ..
800       1        0 
790       2        0
940       3        0
450       0        0(Data point which satisfies the condition but counter should not increment for another 960 values)
1490      0        4(961st Value from the above data point)
1540      0        5
1880      81       0
....      ...     ... (This cycle should continue for rest of the data points)
```

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, what is a 'Lac'? As in: "1.3 Lacs of data values"

Comment: yup, Its 1,30,000 data values

Comment: As you should know, it's an Indian word, so you should not use it here, and should of course fix your question when you see that people don't understand it.

Comment: @James Z Sorry about that, My apologise.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by for cycle like this

Creating sample data and empty column `Indling_Cnt`

```
End_RMP <- round(runif(1800,340,1880),0)
Veh_Spd <- round(runif(1800,0,2),0)
dta <- data.frame(End_RMP,Veh_Spd)
dta$Indling_Cnt <- rep(0,1800)
```

For counting in `Indling_Cnt` you can use forcycle with few if conditions, this is probably not most efficient way to do it, but it should work. There are better and yet more complex solutions. For example using packages as `data.table` as mentioned in other answers.

```
for(i in 2:dim(dta)[1]){

  n <- which(dta$End_RMP[-(1:960)]>=400&dta$Veh_Spd[-(1:960)]==0)[1]+960+960
  if(i>=n){
    if(dta$End_RMP[i]>=400&dta$Veh_Spd[i]==0){
      dta$Indling_Cnt[i] <- dta$Indling_Cnt[i-1]+1
    }else{
      dta$Indling_Cnt[i] <- dta$Indling_Cnt[i-1]
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting a part of expected output, The counter doesn't increment for the first 960 values that is fine, but counter starts to increment from the data point where `Eng_RPM` >= 400 & `Veh_Spd`==0, I wanted the counter to scan for next 960 values from the data point which satisfies the condition and start incrementing.

Comment: @Anup I have changed the code so it satisfies this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do with `data.table` (not using `for` which is known to be slow in R).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
# create a serial number for observation
df[, serial := seq_len(nrow(df))] 
# find series of consective observations matching the condition
# then create internal serial id within each series
df[Eng_RPM > 400 & Veh_Spd == 0,  group_serial:= seq_len(.N),
   by = cumsum((serial - shift(serial, type = "lag", fill = 1)) != 1)  ]
df[is.na(group_serial), group_serial := 0]
# identify observations with group_serial larger than 960, add id
df[group_serial > 960,  Idling_Count := seq_len(.N)]
df[is.na(Idling_Count),  Idling_Count := 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, according to the script this creates 3 more columns but no increment in the counter.

Comment: With my test data, it did. The data: `df <- data.table(Eng_RPM = rep(500, 5000), Veh_Spd = rep(c(1,0,1,0,1), each = 1000))`. This return 80 on 0 entries in Idling_Count (`df[, .N, Idling_Count > 0]`)

Comment: Yup, it works exactly as I wanted it to when I populate the data frame with the same values as yours, but its not working with my data set. I have data in a csv file, I have to read to another data frame.